# How can I troubleshoot multiple CC Graph Reduction events in Firefox that take a lot of time to complete?

Tags: performance, firefox, garbage-collection, profiler

See image below.  I get multiple `CC Graph Reduction` events in a row, which slow down my page loading times tremendously.  I am not sure how to troubleshoot this, or where to look to minimize them.

On a very high level I replaced some Form rendering code from procedural style to OO using Zend Form, but that in itself just generates HTML and does not do anything that I can think of that changes entire behavior of the application to where it was loading under 1 second and now takes over 4 seconds to load.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34924979/2883328) mentions what `CC Graph Reduction` is but not how to troubleshoot it.

[image]

**Update on case**:  It seems that I have inadvertently turned on verbose logging (writing data to disk), which is perhaps the culprit of taking up the bulk of time spent as shown on the graph (in between the red CC marks)

Comment: I'm not seeing any problem here. It only spends a small fraction of wall time in the cycle collector. The actual dip in throughput happens to the right when the minor GCs run, but other stuff seems to be executed at that point too.

Comment: ah.. so you are saying that the red marks is the actual time spent on CC, and *the time in between* those marks is what's to blame for taking extra time.  makes sense

Comment: nothing consuming CPU time seems to be happening between those marks. at least not according to that profile. it might be waiting for IO or a timer